# Change encoding from windows-1251 to utf-8

Tags: php, encode

I'm trying to decode files created in windows-1251 and encode them to UTF-8. Everything works except some special characters such as ÅÄÖåäö. E.g Ä becomes Ž which I then use preg_replace to alter which works fine like below:

`$file = preg_replace("/\Ž/", 'Ä', $file);`

I'm having trouble with Å which shows up like this `<U+008F>`, which I see translates to single shift three and I can't seem to use preg_replace on it?

Comment: Why not find a better initial conversion method?

Comment: Use [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: $file = iconv ( "Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $file );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major builtin functions to do the job, just pick one:

- [Multibyte String](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding):

  ```
  $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251');
  ```
- [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

  ```
  $file = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $file);
  ```

To determine why your homebrew alternative doesn't work we'd need to spend some time reviewing the complete codebase but I can think of some potential issues:

- You're working with mixed encodings yet you aren't using hexadecimal notation or string entities of any kind. It's also unclear what encoding the script file itself is saved as.
- There's no `\Ž` [escape sequence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) in PCRE (no idea what the intention was).
- Perhaps you're replacing some strings more than once.
- Last but not least, have you compiled a complete and correct character mapping database of at least the 128 code points that differ between both encodings?

Comment: mb_convert_encoding worked! I was using the following package to convert which didn't convert it correctly: https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8